# Regular Expressions - preg or substr?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have several values(strings mostly) which I want to process and I was wondering which way is the best to use in my case.

What I will have will be a foreach loop in which I want to have a check and insert into the database edited values.

Structure example:

```
foreach($values as $value) 
{
    //string check is going to be here
    // .....

    //insert the data into the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO results VALUES ('', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Example of values I might get:

> 1. value, value
> 2. Somewhere in the universe
> 3. 3.532523, -55.523525
> 4. value - value

What I want to do is not accept (actually change their value to 'Not given')

```
a) numbers 
b) strings longer than 10 characters 
c) no spaces between the words 
d) if there is a , or - only keep the first part of the string before these
```

A string check which I am testing for example is if I have a value like this 
=> string, string 
I only want to keep the first part, which is done by

> $str = value, value $str = substr($str, 0, stripos($str, ','));

With which technique I will be able to do all these checks better? (preg_match & replace  or substr & stipos)

Comment: "Programming time is more precious than machine time". The easiest is the best, at least here : processing time differences might be quite insignificant in your case (RegExs are much funnier though, I'll admit that)

Answer (score 0):

This regex may match what you want to keep, but will allow numbers and _:

```
/^\w{,10}/
```

Fix numbers allowed with a negative lookahead and avoids _:

```
/^(?=\d{,9}[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]{,10}/
```

If digits are not allowed at all:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{,10}/
```